# Plotting histogram of probability function and results of inverse transform sampling

Tags: python

Here I tried to plot the probability function `P(s)=C/s` and then plot a histogram showing real probability function and then show the results of sampling:

```
import numpy as np

s_min = 1 
s_max = 1000 

# calculate the normalization constant
C = 1 / (np.log(s_max) - np.log(s_min))
u = np.random.rand(int(1000000))
s = s_min * np.exp(u * (np.log(s_max) - np.log(s_min)))
```

```
a = np.log10(min(s))
b = np.log10(max(s))
mybins = np.logspace(a, b, num=17)

plt.hist(s, bins=mybins, density=True, histtype='step', log=True, label='Random Numbers')

x = np.logspace(a, b, num=100)
y = C / x
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', label='Expected Distribution')

plt.xlabel('s')
plt.ylabel('P(s)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but the code is generating an empty plot with labels.

Tried to add %matplotlib inline and nothing changed

Comment: Could you add some picture or something of your output? I tried running this on my system. Had to add the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to it, but in general it worked. It displayed some kind of graph with a lot of stairs and a straight line.

Comment: Also it is important, how you execute it: I put it into my jupyter notebook and executed the whole. This works. But if I for example first execute till `plt.hist`, then from there to `plt.plot` and then afterwards just the remaining few lines, then I think I see what you described. So letting me know how you run that would help a bit I think.

Comment: @Christian I am running in a Jupyter notebook in a separated blocks as it was presented here, still nothing change. I will try to run everything in one cell later. Thanks for the comment!